# get all rows that foreignkey exist on other table by id filtered by employeeid

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I'have the following ORM Query set, it works properly but now i need it to exclude itself from appearing to a user who already added a row with the same id  on the table.

In other words i want the user not to answer the question twice if the user already added an answer to that specific question he will never see the values. here is my query ORM

```
right_now = datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=-10)
partidos = encuesta.objects.filter(fecha__gt=right_now).order_by('fecha')
```

this ORM Query above shows all the Questions from today untill 10 minutes before the due date.

Now i want show only the questions that a specific user has already answered. as you can see below, i need only to appear those questions he has not answered yet but still being filtered by the date and same order.

Any ideas?

[image]

Here is my model.

models.py

```
class equipo(models.Model):

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
bandera = StdImageField(upload_to='bandera/%Y/%m/%d',
                        variations={
                        'large':(53,53, False),
                        'thumbnail': (70, 26, False)})

GRUPOS = (
    ('A', 'Grupo A'),
    ('B', 'Grupo B'),
    ('C', 'Gropo C'),
    ('D', 'Gropo D'),
    ('E', 'Gropo E'),
    ('F', 'Gropo F'),
    ('G', 'Gropo G'),
    ('H', 'Gropo H'),
)

grupo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GRUPOS)

def banderaEquipo(self):
    return '<img src="/media/%s">' % (self.bandera.thumbnail)

banderaEquipo.allow_tags = True

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.nombre


class encuesta(models.Model):

equipoA = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoA')
golesEquipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
equipoB = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoB')
golesEquipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)

ETAPA = (
    ('1', 'Primera Etapa'),
    ('2', 'Octavos De Final'),
    ('3', 'Cuartos De Final'),
    ('4', 'Semifinal'),
    ('5', 'Final'),
    ('6', '3ra Posicion')
)

etapa = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ETAPA)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s Vs. %s" % (unicode(self.equipoA), unicode(self.equipoB))


class respuesta(models.Model):

encuesta = models.ForeignKey(encuesta)
empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
empleado = models.ForeignKey(empleado)
equipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
equipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=1)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s" % (unicode(self.encuesta))
```

Comment: please explain models: encuesta - this is question? respuesta - this is answer? what foreign key connects user to answer: empresa? empleado?

Comment: Having an example with english variables would probably make it easier to answer this question.

Comment: @zymud  yes indeed question=encuesta and answer=respuesta and respuesta is asociated to encuesta by a foreignkey and has a empleado = user to see who it belongs to. What i need is to bring all encuestas = answers that does not exist in respuestas=answers by the current user = empleado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea:

```
Question.objects.exclude(answers__user=user)
```

In your case (if you add related_name encuestas to respuesta FK field encuesta):

```
encuesta.objects.exclude(respuesta__empleado=user).filter(fecha__gt=right_now).order_by('fecha')
```

Comment: thank you and thank you for your time. but instead of encuestas was respuesta :) partidos = encuesta.objects.exclude(respuesta__empleado=session_empleado).filter(
                fecha__gt=ahora_mismo).order_by('fecha')